# Filelauncher save files

Tags: windows-phone, launcher, windows-phone-8

Let's say i have a list of files. When I click on one it will get downloaded and saved into the app's isostore. Then it's opened in the default viewer/editor on the windows phone like this:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

But when I make some changes to the file and want to save it, it can't, because it's a read-only copy of the file. Is there some way to get write-access to the file or else some public/shared (iso)store that every app has access to? The goal is to download the file, edit it and upload it back to the server.

Comment: Is it possible to make a copy of the file, delete the original and upload the new one?

Comment: @Kajzer Yes, that's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Windows Phone documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx), the Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync API is not implemented for the Windows Phone platform:

> Windows Phone 8: This API is not implemented and will throw an
>   exception if called.

In regards to saving the file so that it can be accessed by other applications, this is not possible, unless the file you are dealing with is a photo, in which case you could use the Media Library API.

Comment: That's what I was affraid of, I was just hoping for some kind of loophole. But the statement 'This API is not implemented' is weird, because it works fine. I'll accept your answer but I'm still hoping for some kind of workaround.